# Automation not available in Home app

Tags: automation, ios

I have a bunch of Philips Hue lamps at home and decided to take the new Home app for a spin after installing iOS 10 on my iPhone 6s.

The lamps connected without problem and are fully controllable but when I look at the automation tab the app just informs me that I can make an Apple TV the center of my home. I can find no way to actually create an automation.

First I thought that this was an issue with my Apple TV (4th gen) but while looking around in the setting I was able to reset my home from the Apple TV so some form of connection must have been made.

Maybe related to this is that there is no settings available for Home on the iPhone.

I have tried multiple times to reset my Philips Hue Bridge and reconnect it to the phone but the result is always the same.

Any tips?

**What I see (in Swedish):**
[image: Actual]

**What I expected:**
[image: Expected.]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem here. Can you please be more specific as to what the problem really is? Regarding the absence of settings for Home: have you configured a Home already? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged out of iCloud on my Apple TV and logged in again.
First nothing was different but after a few minutes there suddenly was a HomeKit section under `Settings > Accounts > iCloud` (not under `Settings > iCloud`as suggested by Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/sv-se/HT207057)).

The automation tab in my Home app is now as expected.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please accept your answer.  This helps others who might have the same issue.

Comment: I will but the site tells me I have to wait two days.